# Chamando C++ do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++

Eu tenho uma simulação em C++. Passei essa simulação para JavaScript para o usuário poder brincar com ela no browser, mas ficou muito mais lenta. Se possível, portanto,  gostaria de chamar a própria função em C++ dentro do JavaScript e fazer isso do lado do cliente. É possível?

Comment: Acho que o caminho é por NaCl (Google Native Client). Apesar de nunca ter usado, apenas ouvi falar, falam que é possível executar código nativo no cliente sim. Espero que alguém que tenha usado consiga falar algo sobre isso.

Comment: Está falando de algo como o QT ou está mesmo considerando chamar um programa em C++ a partir de um site em javascript ? ( garanto que a maioria dos browsers não autorizará esta segunda opção).

Comment: @Wakim, `Google Native Client` não roda no lado do cliente como pedido na questão.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun, tem certeza? De uma olhada na descrição: https://developer.chrome.com/native-client.

Comment: Se ver o [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/tutorial/tutorial-part1) verá que ele gera um microservidor para isso e por tanto eu não classificaria como do lado do cliente.

Comment: O Native Client serve justamente para executar código nativo no cliente, diretamente no browser. É provavelmente a solução nesse caso, embora esteja limitado ao Chrome. Não vou escrever uma resposta por que nunca o usei, espero que apareça alguém que já. @Kyllopardiun O servidor do tutorial é apenas para enviar a página e o código binário ao cliente, ele não executa nada.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de partir pro NaCl, que é exclusivo do Chrome, tente usar o [Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/), um compilador baseado no LLVM que transforma código C e C++ em [asm.js](http://asmjs.org). Asm.js é um subconjunto do JavaScript que os engines modernos conseguem otimizar bem e roda com desempenho quase nativo.

A [instalação é bem tranquila](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html). O site também tem um [tutorialzinho](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html).

Comment: Interessante, não é bem o que estava procurando mas não custa tentar. Vou testar e depois retorno com o resultado (se realmente houve ganho significativo de performance).

Answer (score 1):

Além das opções apontadas, tambem seria possivel usar o [Node-Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) 
que embarca o node.js + a engine do chrome.

Executa como um programa normal, mas parece um Browser, limitado apenas a aplicação que você deseja mostrar.

Dessa forma você pode controlar tanto o cliente javascript quando o backend em C++ e empacotar tudo como uma aplicação só. A unica limitação é que o seu usuário teria que instalar o executável, mas se isso nao for um problema, acredito ser a opção que te da maior flexibilidade com o minimo de dor de cabeça possível, comparado ao Nacl(learning overhead) ou ao Emscripten(runtime overhead)

Comment: Se o usuário precisa instalar o executável, por que não distribuir a versão original escrita em C++?